# Changing the customer's password from adminpanel. Where can I find a method which is responsible for that?

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, admin-panel, adminform, password

In Customers/Manage Customers I can select a customer and then in tab "account information" I have a section "Password Management" where I can change a password for selected customer.

[image: password management]

I found out that code responsible for those fields is localized in `Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cusomer/Edit/Tab/Account.php` and it is ok, but my question is how to find **where and which method is calling to change the password after click the save button** in administration panel and additionaly how to find where and which method is calling to send an e-mail with new password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code responsible for changing in the `saveAction` of the `app/code/code/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php` file:

```
if ($customer->getId()&& !empty($data['account']['new_password'])
                && Mage::helper('customer')->getIsRequireAdminUserToChangeUserPassword()
            ) {
                //Validate current admin password
                if (isset($data['account']['current_password'])) {
                    $currentPassword = $data['account']['current_password'];
                } else {
                    $currentPassword = null;
                }
                unset($data['account']['current_password']);
                $errors = $this->_validateCurrentPassword($currentPassword);
            }
```